# For 須, what does "to make (time) pliant" mean?

Tags: etymology

| 詞類 | 英文意義 |
| --- | --- |
| adj. | necessary |
| modal v. | must |
| n. | beard, whiskers (arch.) ; moment |
| v. | have to; wait; expect |
|  | Table from [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%A0%88). |

**Question 1.**
Why does 須 mean both "must" and "wait; expect"? "must" is way more forceful and urgent than "wait; expect"!

> ### Etymology 1 [[on Wiktionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A0%88#Etymology_1)
>
> #### “to wait”
>
> [Schuessler (2007)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:About_Chinese/references#S), reconstructing the Old Chinese as **sno*, suggests that it is probably a causative derivation from [懦](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%87%A6#Chinese) (*OC *njo*, “weak; soft”), literally **“to make (time) pliant”**.

**Question 2.** English and Chinese are not my native languages. I have no clue what **“to make (time) pliant”** means! Time is abstract and intangible. How on earth can you  "ply" time?!?!?!?!

Comment: 須(must) is also used as the simplified 鬚 (beard, whiskers)

Comment: [The given reference](https://books.google.co.jp/books?redir_esc=y&id=nIvqAC7FNBQC&q=pliant#v=onepage&q&f=false) has [this entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCbPw.png) which refers to 懦臑 as being literally translated to "make (time) pliant = stretch (time)", and refers to [this entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzHsS.png).  I don't know if any of this is related to 須.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

哈哈！

First off, etymology is not a science, it is more of a guessing game. That's why they often write PIE roots with *something, like *en, because there is no direct evidence, just lots of people looking at other languages and surmising.

Second off: don't simply believe what you read, especially on wikis.

Third off: Don't trust a German, even one from Hawaii, whose name derives from schusselig, meaning unconcentrated, unbalanced and uncontrolled.

> Component 須   from person-head (页)頁 yè and
> (rem+ 彡 shān whiskers)
> simp 须.   (name- beard (须)須 xū)

Now play the guessing game:
whiskers grow slowly, you must **wait**.
When they are grown, you **must** shave them off again.

Just a guess!

Think about words in your language, whatever that is. For how many of them are you sure about their etymology?

The English word "sad" was originally "sæd", the same as the Modern German word "satt" for "full up, eaten enough"! How did the sense shift??

"pliant time" sounds, well, a far-fetched guess!

Comment: Quote:- "... the Modern German word "satt" for "full up, eaten enough"! How did the sense shift??" Well, if you've eaten enough German sauerkraut and can't eat anymore, wouldn't you be "sad"?

Comment: You don't like sauerkraut?？ What about 韩国的泡菜？

Comment: Kimchi is not my favorite pickled veg., even though it is UNESCO's Representative List of the Intangible Cultural Heritage of Humanity. My favorite is Chinese pickled leek because it reminds me of the time, as a small boy in the 1950's, my mother took me to Classical Cantonese Opera shows, and she always bought a few pickled leeks to keep me from getting bored as the intense sour taste does capture your attention. By some twist of subliminal conditioning, I now find singing Cantonese songs a breeze. Yes, mothers know best.

Comment: Aha, maybe you can help me: how do Cantonese people say 我？The pinyin is ngo5. I asked a girl from 广州，but she just said, "We say wo" So why is the pinyin ngo5?? In 江苏泰州话， 我 is just n

Comment: It is "ngo5", unless she is from some minority Cantonese subgroup which I am not aware of, or she, (I speculate), wants to be politically "safe" by subsuming, or fuzzing her pronunciation to fall into a "grey Twilight zone" where it could sound like a happy marriage of Cantonese and Mandarin, thinking, (in your case wrongly), that you Gwailou wouldn't be the wiser. Try going to "Cantonese Dictionary Online" where, like "Google Translate", it is pronounced. The leading "N" sound is inescapable. Or, listen to this song where "ngo5" is all over the song. https://youtu.be/rKVY7o1aIfg

Answer (score 0):

**1)** "**須**" - 必要(must)，應當(ought to; should)：無**須**。莫**須**有。必**須**。務**須**。**須**要。

**Extended uses:**

- 停留(stop over)：**須**留。
- 片刻，一會兒(awhile): **須**臾。
- 鬍鬚(beard)：**須**眉（男子的代稱）。**須**生（傳統戲劇角色名，即“老生”), 通“鬚生”。
- 像鬍鬚的東西(beard-like matter)：**須**根。觸**須**。

**2) Pliant** (easily being influenced/shaped/formed/bent) was used to explain the word "懦(timid, imbecile)", which has nothing to do with "須".